# How can I select part of a line in Vim

Tags: vim, ex

I have a line of text that looks like this

```
foo bar http://www.example.com -> baz
```

I want yank the url part using ex. Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

To clarify. I want to do something like this `:y/http:.*\.com/` from the command line. But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While on the beginning of a line,

```
wwviWy
```

will yank the URL part while not changing the cursor position.

---

If you want to do it *as a command*

```
:execute "normal! wwviWy0"
```

does the same thing.

Comment: Why `:execute` instead of `:normal!` directly? With @Benoit suggestion, it can be as short as `:norm! 2WyE`

Comment: @sidyll - I'm sure it can be shortened/improved in many ways. This one, however is the first that came to mind, and I rarely use pre-numbers, so ... and the OP got his solution. Moving on ...

Comment: @sidyll - Also, I consider it bad practice using abbreviations in .vim files (for when typing, ok, but not in scripts). They make an already hard to read language completely unreadable. Prefer the full form wherever possible.

Comment: @ldigas I understand. However the real point of my comment was intended to be the (useless) use of `:execute` as a "wrapper". You can call `:normal` directly. :-)

Comment: @sidyll - Oh, yes, you're right about that. I prefer this way, because I don't have to think two case scenarious; with and without escape characters. This way "it just works".

Answer (score 2):

The URL fits the definition of a WORD, so you can do it with `yW` when the cursor is at the beginning.

Comment: Yeah, but how can it be done from the command line. I want to be able to do something like `:y/http:.*\.com/` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `/http` to get at the begining of the URL if I were on a different line, or <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> if I were on the same line and then <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>  (last key is space).

Comment: The "`t `" part is generally better expressed as `E`.

Comment: @bitmask I generally prefer `t ` because it's generic (ie. it's not that I always look for a space), not only word-related. This way I don't have to use 2 different shortcuts or care about word-separators.

Answer (score 0):

```
normal /http^v^m^v^mv2fm <Enter>
```

Where ^v = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> and ^m = <kbd>Enter</kbd>